# Probability: How to play the following game to maximise the value

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, game-theory

Suppose I have a box where you can pick to receive 50 or a second box. If you pick 50 you walk away with 50 but if you pick the second box you then will have a 50% chance of receiving 1 or 50% chance of receiving another box. This process keeps repeating up to 4 times, see below.

Start off box 0
Box 0 contains 50 or Box 1, you can pick
Box 1 contains 50% chance at 1 or 50% chance at Box 2
Box 2 contains 105 or Box 3, you can pick
Box 3 contains 50% chance at 1 or 50% chance at Box 4
Box 4 contains 221 or Box 5, you can pick
Box 5 contains 50% chance at 1 or 50% chance at Box 6
Box 6 contains 465 or Box 7, you can pick
Box 7 contains 50% chance at 1 or 50% chance at Box 8
Box 8 contains 977, this is the last box

How would you play this game to maximise the reward? Based on my calculations it seems like it's always worth it to go for box 8 and 977 since the expected value is 62?

My calculation is as follows.

Expected value = 0.5*1 + 0.25*1 + 0.125*1 + 0.0625*1 + 0.0625*977 = 62, this is greater than the initial choice of picking 50 so you should always go until the last box.

Comment: There are four separate decisions to be made. Are there any where the money is larger than the expected reward of the mystery box?

Comment: No the only options are what I wrote in the example. The mystery box retard is the same each time it won't change randomly.

Comment: Once you've opened box 2, you have a choice between box 3 and 105. What is the expected value of box 3? Is it larger than 105?

Comment: yes because box 3 will either give you 1 or 50% chance at box 4 which contains 221

so the expected value is 0.5 * 1 + 0.5*221?

Comment: Not quite. Box 4 doesn't just contain 221--it contains your choice between 221 and box 5. So its value depends on which of those is larger. Ultimately, to do this properly, you should work backwards. Start with the known value of box 8, use that to find the value of box 7, and so on until you reach box 1.